# first free MFC Resource ID

Tags: c++, mfc

I need to find the first free "control resource ID" (**IDC_**) in a MFC-Project to create new control elements at runtime.

My intention is to write a management class, that keeps track of the resources at runtime. To initialize this class I need to know what the last Resource ID assigned by "**APStudio**" (the WYSIWYG Resource Editor of VS2010) is.

Looking at the "**Resource.h**" I can find **#defines** for this ID (**_APS_NEXT_CONTROL_VALUE**) - this value is updated by the WYSIWYG Editor and should solve my problem. Sadly this define is not active while compilation but only while using APStudio (**#ifdef APSTUDIO_INVOKED**).
Removing the #ifdef leads to the ID being defined, but not being updated by APStudio anymore (just in case there are any manual changes).
In General I would like to leave the whole project (**Resource.h**, etc.) like it is, so my class can be used universally.

I hope I somehow made my problem clear - if not, feel free to ask.
Thank you very much, for reading this and helping me out with this :-)

Comment: There is no standard way to query for the first "free" resource ID. Even if there was, you'd still fail the *"what if someone else did this"* test, e.g. another dialog that creates controls at runtime and assigns IDs. MFC has a document that describes the ID ranges in use ([TN020: ID Naming and Numbering Conventions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t2zechd4.aspx)), but that's not going to help much either. If you really want to implement a management class, reference controls through their `HWND`s, since IDs need not be universally unique.

Comment: I was afraid to read this answer. Already found the TN020, but came to the same conclusion you did. I think I will dive into using HWNDs - thank you very much.

Comment: `HWND`s universally identify windows, so they are the natural choice as a lookup/management key. This will also deal with situations, where multiple windows share the same ID. This is common for Static controls, for example, that usually all share the same ID: `IDC_STATIC`.

Answer (score 0):

The control's ID must only be unique in the scope of its parent window.

For the purpose of uniquely identifying all controls in the application, Help system, for example, combines the Dialog's ID with Control's into a DWORD used as a help topic.

Also, please not the the first "free" ID doesn't necessarily starts a sequence of free IDs.

To get a list of all used IDs, you can enumerate all the child windows, get there IDs and go from there. Alternatively, assuming that there isn't a whole lot of controls, you can simply test integer values in a loop:

```
ind freeID(0);
for(;;++freeID)
    if(GetDlgItem(hDlg, freeID) == 0)
        break;
```

Comment: Not entirely correct: Different controls with the same parent can share the same ID, if the application doesn't need to distinguish between those controls by ID. Static controls commonly do this. Enumerating all child windows is not generally feasible, as it requires creating **all** windows, and run through all control paths, that dynamically create controls. A `HWND` uniquely identifies a window/control in the system.